# How to infres types with Partial in react-redux

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, typescript-typings, partial

I think for a long time and I can’t understand.
Here is the code:

```js
const mapState = (state: AppStateType) => ({
  users: getUsers(state),
  pageSize: getPageSize(state),
  totalUsersCount: getTotalUsersCount(state),
  currentPage: getCurrentPage(state),
  isFetching: getIsFetching(state),
  followingInProgress: getFollowingInProgress(state)
})

const mapDispatch = {
  toggleFollowingInProgress,
  requestUsers,
  follow,
  unfollow
}

const connector = connect(mapState, mapDispatch)

type PropsFromRedux = ConnectedProps<Partial<typeof connector>>
...
export default connector(UsersContainer)
```

When compiling, I see this error:

```js
Users.container.tsx(44,16):
Property 'requestUsers' does not exist on type 'never'.  TS2339
```

It seems he writes about this.props

```js
class UsersContainer extends React.Component<PropsType>
{
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.requestUsers(this.props.currentPage, this.props.pageSize)
  }
```

requestUsers is thunk:

```js
export const requestUsers = (page: number, pageSize: number) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  dispatch(toggleIsFetching(true))
}
```

Setting the return to void gives nothing.
Help please

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in Partial, it is not suitable for this task and confuses reading the code.

```js
type mapStateType = {
  users: userType[]
  pageSize: number
  totalUsersCount: number
  currentPage: number
  isFetching: boolean
  followingInProgress: number[]
}

type mapDispatchType = {
  toggleFollowingInProgress: (isFetching: boolean, userID: number) => void
  requestUsers: (page: number, pageSize: number) => void
  follow: (userID: number) => void
  unfollow: (userID: number) => void
}

type ownType = {
  onPageChanged?: (page: number) => void
}

type PropsType = mapStateType & mapDispatchType & ownType
```

Exporting propsType and application on it Partial gives an error in which the type is complemented indefined. Therefore, I strictly defined the types in each component and the errors went away.